# Do PhoneGap requires Internet access in order to run

Tags: cordova, phonegap, phonegap-desktop-app

I have download PhoneGap (PhoneGapSetup-win32.exe) on a Windows 10 machine. However, when I try to run it, it will struck at the loading screen. (I do not know if it is trying to attempt to go to the Internet)

So I spent time searching and found that there are a lots of people facing the same problem. Someone provide a new file for PhoneGap (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/releases/download/0.3.0/PhoneGap-0.3.0-loading-fix-2-win32.zip) which at the end, the PhoneGap works.

However, a new problem occur when I try to create a new project. It will popup a message saying 'getaddrinfo ENOENT github.com443'. Oh my god, why is it so difficult to create a new project.

So, I would like to know if PhoneGap indeed requires Internet access in order to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Internet is required because apps created by PhoneGap are compile and build on PhoneGap Cloud.

Comment: This is not always the case for PhoneGap CLI, although there is the option to build apps on the cloud, it is not needed. PhoneGap Build does require internet though.